# Display recents posts from specific category only on homepage

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the 3 latest posts form a specific category and it is working quite well.
But as soon as I want to restrict the display on the home page only, my function is not working anymore.

```
add_action( 'um_theme_before_content', 'extranet_header' );

function extranet_header() {
    // Get the posts form the "Communiques" category
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=communiques&posts_per_page=3' );
    
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        // Render posts link and title in an ordered list
        echo '<div id="communiques">'.
             '<h4>Les derniers communiqués</h4>'.
             '<ul class="administration-notice">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>'.
                 '<h4><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="Cliquez pour en savoir plus...">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>'.
                 '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>'.
                 '<a class="admin-notice-button" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="Cliquez pour en savoir plus...">Lire la suite</a>'.
                 '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>' .
             '<div class="communiques-footer">'.
             '<a class="communiques-button" href="/communiques/">Voir les anciens communiqués</a>'.
             '</div><!--/.communiques-footer-->'.
             '</div><!--/#communiques-->';
    } else { // No post found
        echo 'Aucun communiqué';
    }
    //  Reset the original main query
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

When I add is_home() the result of the function returns no posts:

```
add_action( 'um_theme_before_content', 'extranet_header' );

function extranet_header() {
    // Get the posts form the "Communiques" category
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=communiques&posts_per_page=3' );
    
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() && $the_query->is_home() ) {
        // Render posts link and title in an ordered list
        echo '<div id="communiques">'.
             '<h4>Les derniers communiqués</h4>'.
             '<ul class="administration-notice">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>'.
                 '<h4><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="Cliquez pour en savoir plus...">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>'.
                 '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>'.
                 '<a class="admin-notice-button" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="Cliquez pour en savoir plus...">Lire la suite</a>'.
                 '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>' .
             '<div class="communiques-footer">'.
             '<a class="communiques-button" href="/communiques/">Voir les anciens communiqués</a>'.
             '</div><!--/.communiques-footer-->'.
             '</div><!--/#communiques-->';
    } else { // No post found
        echo 'Aucun communiqué';
    }
    //  Reset the original main query
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try wrapping your query in the front page conditional, as opposed to running the query and seeing if it's "home".  This way the query doesn't run unless it's the homepage vs. running it every time then checking for the page.

Plus, `is_home()` refers to the posts page and not the "home" page as you might think of it so your settings could be misaligned.  Check in Settings->Reading.

Give this a try:

```
add_action( 'um_theme_before_content', 'extranet_header' );

function extranet_header() {

    // Check for the page that is set as the "Static home page" in settings.
    if ( is_front_page() ) {

    // Get the posts form the "Communiques" category
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=communiques&posts_per_page=3' );
    
    if ( $the_query->have_posts()) {
        // Render posts link and title in an ordered list
        echo '<div id="communiques">'.
             '<h4>Les derniers communiqués</h4>'.
             '<ul class="administration-notice">';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>'.
                 '<h4><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="Cliquez pour en savoir plus...">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>'.
                 '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>'.
                 '<a class="admin-notice-button" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="Cliquez pour en savoir plus...">Lire la suite</a>'.
                 '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>' .
             '<div class="communiques-footer">'.
             '<a class="communiques-button" href="/communiques/">Voir les anciens communiqués</a>'.
             '</div><!--/.communiques-footer-->'.
             '</div><!--/#communiques-->';
    } else { // No post found
        echo 'Aucun communiqué';
    }
    //  Reset the original main query
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    }

}
```

Comment: No problem glad it worked for you.  You can mark this as an answer for others to find as well.